# Home made find function runs but returns nothing

Tags: python, find

I'm new to python and have been working on problems to try and learn some programming.  My problem is in the second function of this program. What I want the program to return is each position that the substring to look for is at in the input_string.

i.e.

```
multifind("Ni! Ni! Ni! Ni!", "Ni", 0, 20)
```

should return `"0,4,8,12"`

However, when I run this in my IDE, the program runs but returns nothing.  I am wondering if anyone could show me where/what in the program that is causing this?
Preferably in a manner that a beginner could understand.

```
def find(input_string, substring, start, end):

    x = (len(substring))

    for i in range(0, len(input_string)):
        if input_string[i:(i+x)] == substring:
            return i
        else:
            i += 1
    return -1


def multi_find(input_string, substring, start, end):

    loop = True
    nulist = ""
    r = start - 1
    while loop:
        r = find(input_string,substring, r + 1, end)
        if r != -1:
            if nulist == "":
                nulist += str(r)
            else:
                nulist += "," + str(r)
        else:
            loop = False
    return nulist
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to return -1 in find function?

Comment: The bodies of your functions need to be indented. You can't be sloppy in python indentation.

Comment: Your `find` function doesn't make use of `start` and `end`, it always searches from the beginning.

Comment: Instead of returning a comma-separated string, you should return a list.

Comment: The reason this file doesn't give any output when run is that **all you do is define two functions**. You never call any of them. Print out the result of that example call you provided --  `print multifind("Ni! Ni! Ni! Ni!", "Ni", 0, 20)` at the bottom of your code, and the program will display output.

Comment: tried print, still just runs with nothing returned

Comment: Since `find` ignores the `start` and `end` arguments, you have an infinite loop because it keeps finding the first match every time through the `while` loop.

Comment: Fix your `find` function and then `multifind` will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using start in find, try:

```
def find(input_string, substring, start):

    x = (len(substring))

    for i in range(start, len(input_string)):
        if input_string[i:(i+x)] == substring:
            return i
        else:
            i += 1

    return -1


def multi_find(input_string, substring, start):

    loop = True
    nulist = ""
    r = start - 1
    while loop:
        r = find(input_string,substring, r + 1)
        if r != -1:
            if nulist == "":
                nulist += str(r)
            else:
                nulist += "," + str(r)
        else:
            loop = False
    return nulist

print multi_find("Ni! Ni! Ni! Ni!", "Ni", 0)
```

Comment: You're using `start`, but not `end`.

Comment: @Barmar I made the correction, delete end, I think it is not necesary.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the end value needs to be in there...but i guess since you removed it, that would mean the function wasn't really ever using it?

Comment: Is unnecessary, because you can get the end using start and len function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not precisely what you want but I will post the one liner function for this using regular expresions

```
def multifind(input_string, substring):
    return [m.start() for m in re.finditer(input_string, substring)]
```

This finds all *input_string* first index matches in *substring* and returns it as list.

Comment: He's trying to learn how to implement these functions himself. Using the built-in functions defeats the purpose.

Comment: I don't think learning Python means write Python while thinking of C++ or Java code. The first think of learning Python is start thinking like Python developer. Personal opinion.

Comment: Touché. I agree with you I must have been distracted while reading the problem and understanding the needs. Anyway I will leave this for curious people :)